# Logic apps ARM deployment fails for API connections using OAuth that already exist and are connected

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

Recently I'm gettings errors when deploying logic apps using ARM templates. I get the errors for certain API connections that are used by the logic apps. The error I receive is:

> Input parameters are invalid. See details for more information. Details:errorCode: ParameterNotDefined. Message: Parameter  '$connectionCreator' is not allowed on the connection since it was not defined as a connection parameter when the API was registered.

I only get these errors for existing and *authenticated* connections of type `dynamicscrmonline` and `azureeventgrid`. As long as the connection doesn't exist or isn't yet authenticated, the deployment succeeds. It appears to be happening only with API connections that use OAuth. This used to work in the past and I'm not sure what changed.

This is an example of a connection that gives me the error:

```json
{
  "type": "MICROSOFT.WEB/CONNECTIONS",
  "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
  "name": "[parameters('dynamicscrmonline_1_Connection_Name')]",
  "location": "westeurope",
  "properties": {
    "api": {
      "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', 'westeurope', '/managedApis/', 'dynamicscrmonline')]"
    },
    "displayName": "[parameters('dynamicscrmonline_1_Connection_DisplayName')]"
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with Azure AD API and send grid.
Try to delete the existing connections API associated to your existing Logic App and then redeploy.

It works for me.